# how to add '+' sign in dynamic sql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I hope you can help me with this..I want to get the sum of all rows in the result query.. this is the sql query I have so far..

```
DECLARE @earninglist varchar(1000)
   Set @earninglist=STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT '],['
        +LTRIM([Description]) FROM
        PR_Earnings 
        ORDER BY '],[' + LTRIM([Description])
                    FOR XML PATH('')
                    ), 1, 2, '')+']'

Declare @sql varchar(max)
set @sql='Select '+@earninglist+' from earnings;'
exec(@sql);
```

say that earning list contains this fields: 'Cola','Incentives' How can I declare @earninglist so that I can get this following query:

```
set @sql='Select Coalesce([Cola],0)+Coalesce([Incentives],0) as total from earnings'
```

hope you can help me..thanks alot.

Comment: sorry for the down votes i am just a newbie on this one and I just want to know the reason why.. and if you are the right person to teach me with this one can you teach me how to do it properly without google and without link reference? I just only got that script from this site and just trying it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be aware that your script is open to sql-injections. Description can be written to drop your tables.

```
DECLARE @earninglist varchar(1000)
Set @earninglist=STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT '],0),coalesce(['
    +LTRIM([Description]) FROM
    PR_Earnings (description)
    ORDER BY '],0),coalesce([' + LTRIM([Description])
                FOR XML PATH('')
                ), 1, 5, '')+'], 0)'
```

You can test with this script:

```
SELECT STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT '],0),coalesce(['
+LTRIM([Description]) FROM
(values ('cola'),('Incentives')) PR_Earnings (description)
ORDER BY '],0),coalesce([' + LTRIM([Description])
                FOR XML PATH('')
                ), 1, 5, '')+'], 0)'
```

Result:

```
coalesce([cola],0),coalesce([Incentives], 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there are other much more elegant ways  but...why not just replace the first occurrence of ")" with ")+" in the variable?